# Find $E|X_p-X_q|^2$

Tags: probability

I have a slight problem with following assigment. We take points $P=(X_p,Y_p)$ and $Q=(X_q,Y_q)$ from square with vertices in $(-1,0)$$(0,-1)$$(1,0)$$(0,1)$ We take $P$ and $Q$ independently with geometrical probability. I need to calculate $E|X_p-X_q|^2$. What should be my approach here? I will be very gratefull for a hints.

Comment: Maybe try to expand the expectation term?

Comment: $X_p$ and $X_q$ follows a $Uniform(-1,1)$ distribution and are independent of each other. $E((X_p-X_q)^2) = E((X_p)^2) + E((X_q)^2) - 2E(X_p X_q)$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: $$ E((X_p)^2) + E((X_q)^2) - 2E(X_p X_q)=E((X_p)^2) + E((X_q)^2)- 2E(X_p)E( X_q) =E((X_p)^2) + E((X_q)^2)$$ Now lets calculate $E((X_p)^2)=\int_{-1}^{1} x^2 dx = \frac{2}{3}$ and same for $E((X_p)^2)$. My concern is, are they really uniformly distributed? This square is rotated $90$ degres so intuitivly closer we get to $0Y$ axis the probability increases. I tired to find distribution explicitly : $P(X<t)$ but result I got is ugly.